# Equivalent of mod_proxy_html for Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, reverse-proxy, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway as a reverse proxy. Behind that proxy I have an Angular Web App the code of which I can't modify.
The problem is that the webapp uses relative hyperlinks so when accessing the proxied web app by URL *http://localhost:8080/webapp/* the app omits the *webapp* part in it's hyperlinks and the hyperlinks look like *http://localhost:8080/destination/* instead of *http://localhost:8080/webapp/destination*.
Apache Httpd has module for it called mod_proxy_html that rewrites the paths in HTML content served by the proxy. Is there something similar in Spring Cloud Gateway or maybe one should use reverse proxy functionality only for REST APIs?

Answer (score 0):

try:
application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: rewritepath_route
        uri: http://localhost:8080
        predicates:
        - Path=/destination
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/(?<segment>/?.*), /webapp/$\{segment}
```

---

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-rewritepath-gatewayfilter-factory

Comment: This will work only if the webapp in question is the only one being put behind the gateway because all paths are rewritten regardless of where they came.
This means that something like /webapp2/stuff would be rewritten to /webapp/webapp2/stuff and that's wrong. 
Is there a way to support this usecase?

Comment: `predicates` above is used to determine which paths the filters should be applied to
so in the example above, only `/destination` would be rewritten to `/webapp/destination`

Comment: see spring cloud gateway docs link above for example with wildcard